# Spring Retry ignores "noRetryFor" (retries for all exceptions)

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I am implementing a retry logic using the spring retry template that needs to retry for all exceptions with the exclusion of one, that I throw under a condition.
However, spring retries for that exception as well and I can't get it to change.

Here is my method, in which someException inherits from broadException:

```
    @Retryable(noRetryFor = {SomeException.class}, maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${retry.delay:2000}", multiplier = 2))
    @Override
    public void someMethod(String id) throws broadException{
        Optional<Object> object = repository.getObject(id);
        if (object.isPresent()) {
            //do stuff
        }
        else{
            throw new SomeException();
        }
    }
```

Why is spring ignoring my "noRetryFor"?

I tried removing the brackets around SomeException.class but it made no difference.

Comment: I am seeing something similar using Spring Retry 1.3.2.  I have
    `@Retryable(backoff = @Backoff(100), exclude = {EntityNotFoundException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class,
            IllegalStateException.class})
    @Transactional` and the excluded exceptions keep getting retried.  What's odd is I have written tests for Spring to validate and they work as expected.

Comment: @garyrussell any chance you can bail us out?! Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me; see the answer.

Comment: Please show the way how do you invoke `someMethod`?

Comment: @kellyfj Can you check the exception type. I am not sure whether retry works for exceptions which are not RuntimeException. Does  BroadException extends RuntimeException?

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me -

2.0.0:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So75502613Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75502613Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            foo.doIt("fail");
            foo.doIt("someEx");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    @Retryable(noRetryFor = SomeException.class)
    void doIt(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if ("someEx".equals(in)) {
            throw new SomeException();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Recover
    void recover(Exception ex, String in) {
        System.out.println(in + ":" + ex.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SomeException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

```
fail
fail
fail
fail:IllegalStateException
someEx
someEx:SomeException
```

1.3.4:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So75502613Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75502613Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            foo.doIt("fail");
            foo.doIt("someEx");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    @Retryable(exclude = SomeException.class)
    void doIt(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if ("someEx".equals(in)) {
            throw new SomeException();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Recover
    void recover(Exception ex, String in) {
        System.out.println(in + ":" + ex.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SomeException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

```
fail
fail
fail
fail:IllegalStateException
someEx
someEx:SomeException
```